# Padding messing with background color

Tags: html, css, colors, background, padding

I got a problem with my footer background. It seems like the height of the #pagefooter is 0 and the background color is only applied to the padding, vertical which 2x 25px.

I tried several things, but i didn't find a solution.
What's wrong here?

///THE HTML

```
<div id="pagefooter">
    <footer>
        <nav id="f1" class="footernav">
            <h1>Misc</h1>
            </br>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Lorem</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">ipsum</a>
                <li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">dolor</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">sit</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">amet</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav id="f2" class="footernav">
            <!-- SOME MENU -->
        </nav>
        <nav id="f3" class="footernav">
            <!-- SOME MENU -->
        </nav>
        <nav id="f4" class="footernav">
            <!-- SOME MENU -->
        </nav>
    </footer>
</div>
```

///THE CSS

```
#pagefooter {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    padding:25px 100px;
}
.footernav {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/AR3AC/

Comment: Could you explain clearly what is the result you want to get?

Comment: the background color of the whole #pagefooter should be #1a1a1a. From "top to bottom" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, `#pagefooter` contains only floated elements which make the parent element have no height (and therefore no background colour). To work around this, set the overflow property to auto:

```
#pagefooter {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    padding: 25px 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The height of the pagefooter is never set as far as I can tell. Add a line into #pagefooter so like this to explicitly state the height you want:

```
#pagefooter {
    background-color: #aaa;
    height: 100px;
    padding:25px 100px;
}
```

I'm not sure if that answers your question, but that's a good place to start.

Comment: I dont want to set a specific height, as i don't know how many li's i'm going to have. It works fine with Ben's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Now and then I'll get an issue with overflow:auto. In case you do, another way to deal with this is to put an empty clearing div right before . It can just be `<div style="clear:both"></div>`. (I generally make a class ".clear" which has clear:both. Makes it easy to troubleshoot this sort of thing by just testing with a `<div class="clear"></div>` to see if floats are the issue.

Comment: Floats were not the issue here i think, but it's good to know some other techniques to try ;)

Comment: Actually, floats ARE the issue - the reason the overflow: auto that Ben suggested works is because it forces the container to recognize the size of floated content (floated content exists outside of the page flow, and therefore normally has no height so far as containing elements are concerned). The trouble with that is that if the content is clipped by the size of the container, overflow:auto forces scroll bars, which you may not want. A clearing div essentially makes the parent div see the size of floated content, and then allows you to apply an overflow rule as usual.

Comment: PS - The way I wrote that sounded a bit dickish. Sorry about that - not meant to be dickish at all. Just wanted to explain what was going on! :)